# Save string in a secure store where no user has access to

Tags: c#, encryption, store

I want to save a normal text string into a secure store, where no user has access to and therefore cannot change any text of the string.

Is there a possibility to save a string in a kind of a "secure store", maybe encrypt the string, which is currently working with RSA/AES under Windows with CSP containers. But I DON'T want to save the encrypted string right into a file, because the user should not be able to change the string.

There is NO internet or network connection. So saving on a server is NOT an option. I need to save it locally!

Is there any possibility to store a string securely (under Windows)?

Comment: Will the user (or rather your process) ever have need to read that value back again? If so, the technical answer to your question is an obvious "no" -- what your application can do, the user can do, by definition, and all the rest is mere obfuscation. If the value will never be read back again by your process, it's doable, but only by handing it off to another, more privileged process. If all you want to do is protect against naive tampering, cryptographic signing is an option (but the user can still get the key, of course).

Comment: *Is there any possiblity to store a string securely?*  Question is too broad ... but the answer is **no** ... user with admin rights and enough programming skills will find the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO. Any user with physical access to the machine can alter the hard disk. He can, e.g., install a proxy between the hard disk controller and the OS and you would never notice.

Even easier: if the user has Administrator access to the machine, he can alter every file on the system without ever performing any hardware tricks.

You should moreover clarify if the user should not be able to READ or not be able to ALTER the string. Also: should your application (which runs under the access rights of the user...) be able to read the string?